# Why would border-radius round the corners of a parent container, but not on it's direct child image element?

Tags: html, css, containers, border-radius

I have this problem specifically when building card components.

Here's some parent container to a challenge from frontendmentor:

```
.grid-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* min-height: 100%; */
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 350px;
  

  display: grid;
  align-self: center;
  place-items: center;

  gap: 1.5rem; 
}
```

```
#hero-image {
  /* border-radius: 15px; */
  width: 100%;
  /* margin: 16px 0px; */
}
```

without the border-radius property applied to the element, the corners do not round.

I've wrapped the image element inside a div and a picture tag. Both resulted in the corners remaining sharp; no rounded corners. The only solution is to apply the border-radius values to both the parent container and the child image element.

Here is the link to the solution and to the repo.

https://funupulu.github.io/frontend-mentor/newbie/order-summary-component-main/index.html

https://github.com/funupulu/funupulu.github.io/tree/main/frontend-mentor/newbie/order-summary-component-main

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the two following attributes to your **parent element** in order **to reshape your child** `border-radius` based on your parent element the CSS to add:

```css
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: is the position : relative really necessary ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think so

Comment: Only off the top of my head, generally speaking most of the web devs I follow discourage using the position property. Why?

Comment: @Guiver styling the a website using specified positioned elements would be considered sloppy because, for example, any new content could easily mess up your carefully-crafter layout (plus having the specify different specific definitions for the various screen sizes) - for some items, not bound to change often, it could be OK (as a pragmatic exception to the rule)